# Initialise global array of arrays of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am declaring an array of struct this way :

```
struct struct_name tab1[6] ={ {"1487" ,0.144}, {"148",2.1},    {"45",0.01}, {"12475847",0.52}, {"46",1.4}, {"0",5} };
struct struct_name tab2[7] = { {"1" ,0.9}, {"76",5.1},{"46",0.17},{"4625",0.0},{"46252",1.57},{"12",1.5},{"5",1.2} };
```

This works fine.

Now I need to make `tab1` and `tab2` in one array `global_tab` and still initialize data this way but so far I haven't been able to do so. I tried dynamic allocation like this

```
global_tab = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct struct_name *));
global_tab[0] = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct struct_name));
global_tab[0] = { {"1487" ,0.144}, {"148",2.1}, {"45",0.01}, {"12475847",0.52}, {"46",1.4}, {"0",5} };
```

But I get this error

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
  global_tab[0] ={ {"1487" ,0.144}, {"148",2.1}, {"45",0.01}, {"12475847",0.52}, {"46",1.4}, {"0",5} };
```

I want to be able to do initialize  `global_tab[0]` the same way I did with `tab1`

Comment: Side note: `global_tab[0] = something` then `global_tab[0] = something else` means that the first assignment is pretty much useless. It's like doing `int i = 5; i = 6;`.

Comment: IIRC, C initialiser lists are only available for static and auto storage duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not provide array aggregate assignment. The curly brace construct is available only in initialization expressions<sup>*</sup>. If you would like to place specific data into a dynamically allocated block, you could make a `static` variable with the data, and use `memcpy`, like this:

```
static struct struct_name tmp0[] ={ {"1487" ,0.144}, {"148",2.1},    {"45",0.01}, {"12475847",0.52}, {"46",1.4}, {"0",5} };
global_tab[0] = malloc(sizeof(tmp0));
memcpy(tmp0, global_tab[0], sizeof(tmp0));
```

<sup>*</sup> Some compilers provide struct and array aggregates as an extension, but using this feature makes your code non-portable.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused about **initialization** and **assignment**. These operations are different, despite that they both use `=`:

```
int m = 42;  // initialization
int n;
n = 42;  // assignment
```

The code in error is similar:

```
global_tab[0] = { {"1487" ,0.144}, {"148",2.1}, {"45",0.01}, {"12475847",0.52}, {"46",1.4}, {"0",5} };
```

This is assignment, you can't use the initialization syntax. The C99 **compound literal** is perhaps what you want.

Comment: If `global_tab` wasn't dynamically allocated, it could be initialized.